# What hardware type is for "Graphics Drivers"?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I am using a `Windows 7 64-bit SP1` laptop, and I wanted to update my Graphics Driver

I went to this site and found a driver, but when I unzipped it, I didn't see an executable to install it.
https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/toshiba/laptops-desktops/satellite-l850d/2699
[Driver description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF8kN.png)
[Driver contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVsg9.png)

So, I went to `Device Manager > Action > Add Legacy hardware` but only to find that I needed to specify the category, which I don't know.
[Hardware types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akdYH.png)

Does anyone know which one should I choose? thanks.

Comment: Why do you believe you have that specific GPU?

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't just go straight to AMD for AMD drivers. https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-7000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-7610m 15.7.1 was the last driver set issued for that & many other legacy GPUs. Don't use the beta. The one on the 3rd party site you found is 3 years older.

Comment: You do not want to _add legacy hardware_. You want to _update_ a device driver that is already installed and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware type for your AMD Graphics Driver is 'Display Adapters'.

Comment: There's nothing new here, so it will probably get deleted

Comment: After the edit, it does now answer the question as asked. [It's not really what the OP needs, but this answer is actually what they asked for]

Answer (score 0):

According to what "Driverscape" as found (AMD Radeon HD7610M) you have to download the driver from AMD Official Website [AMD Radeon™ HD 7610M Drivers & Support](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-7000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-7610m)

---

For your information :

1 Driverscape is not really a good way to check or update product (as you saw)

2 Prefer to install GPU-Z to clearly identify what is the exact model of your graphic hardware.

3 Prefer to download the driver from the Official Manufacturer Website or from the Toshiba Website.

---

*Note that your hardware is not maintained anymore and the last driver provided is from 2015-2016*

---

Best Regards